# Why does adding an AVCapturePhotoOutput to my AVCaptureSession cause the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to turn break on iPhone X?

Tags: swift, iphone, avaudiosession

After configuring my video layer as such:

```swift
public class VideoLayerView: UIView {
    override public class var layerClass: Swift.AnyClass {
        return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }
    
    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
    public func configureCaptureLayer(session: AVCaptureSession?) {
        guard let captureLayer = self.layer as? AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer else { return }
        
        captureLayer.session = session
        captureLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    }
}
```

And setting up the session:

```swift
func initializeCamera() {
        guard !captureSession.isRunning else {
            print("Capture session already running")
            return
        }
        guard Permissions.shared.isCameraAuthorized else {
            print("Requesting Camera Permission")
            Permissions.shared.requestCamera { _ in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.initializeCamera()
                }
            }
            return
        }
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
        if let captureDevice = self.captureDevice {
            if let captureDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice), captureSession.canAddInput(captureDeviceInput) {
                captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            } else {
                print("Failed to add capture device input.")
            }
        }

        photoOutput.maxPhotoQualityPrioritization = .quality
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {
            photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
        } else {
            print("Failed to add photo output")
        }
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()

        if let connection = photoOutput.connection(with: .video) {
            connection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = .standard
        }
        
        videolayerView.configureCaptureLayer(session: captureSession)

        sessionQueue.async { [weak self] in
            self?.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }
```

the preview layer displays black on my iPhone X. However it continues to function on other test devices. Removing:

```swift
if captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {
            photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
        } else {
            print("Failed to add photo output")
        }
```

resolves the issue but this code is necessary to capture photos. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to camera state bug in iOS from code written prior (and since removed) that incorrectly configured the camera. Restart your device and the camera will resume functioning.